# insert image into animation heart shape

Tags: css

I have problem with heart beating shape where I want add image inside shape and width is 100%, but image is going behind shape.

https://jsfiddle.net/pphewde8/

```
<div class="heart">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/240/240">
  <span class="left" ></span>
  <span class="right"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a z-index to the image to bring it above the heart layer. To nudge the kitten into position within the heart, set the left and top properties as required. Because the image breaks out of the heart, you can scale it so it fits, with transform:scale(). Putting it all together, you have:

```
img {
  left: 70px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  transform: scale(0.75);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with code to put the image inside the heart.